# Design of technology-neutral policy in the presence of multiple market failures

Tags: welfare-economics, technology

I am studying a paper by [Aisbett, Cheng & Beck](https://www.anu.edu.au/files/document-collection/ZCWP03-21%20Green%20Industrial%20Policy%20and%20Technology%20Neutrality_1%20%281%29_0.pdf) which considers the pros and cons of technological neutrality in green industrial policy.  At the start of section 5.6 it refers to the well-known paper by [Lipsey & Lancaster (1956)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2296233), stating, correctly I believe, that:

> theory shows that in the presence of multiple market failures, attempts to rectify any one failure may exacerbate another and thereby actually make things "worse" (i.e. lead to an even less efficient situation and reduce overall welfare).

It then states:

> A corollary of this theory is that a well-designed technology-neutral strategy toward a multi-dimensional set of goals will involve a set of policy instruments, each one targeted at an identified market failure.

Is this indeed a valid corollary? Three points strike me:

1. Although the paper is generally well referenced, no source is mentioned for this corollary.
2. The passage from "may" in the first proposition to "will" in the corollary suggests dubious logic.
3. I cannot see any obvious reason why some combination of policy instruments might, in conjunction, rectify each of several market failures, without any one policy instrument being targeted at any one market failure.